# Apache mod_fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris, mod-fastcgi

i am trying to configure an apache2 server with mod_fastcgi on solaris 10
so far i have everything installed using CSW

here is my virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1005" "#1006"
DocumentRoot /home/testwh2/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/testwh2/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory />
SetHandler fastcgi-script
Options +ExecCGI
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
FastCgiServer /export/httpd/cgi-bin/php
</VirtualHost>
```

/export/httpd/cgi-bin/php is a hard link to my php interpreter

and here are my errors log

```
FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/home/testwh2/public_html/test.php" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec)
[Fri Aug 17 12:32:27 2012] [error] [client X] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/home/testwh2/public_html/test.php"
[Fri Aug 17 12:40:12 2012] [error] [client X] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/home/testwh2/public_html/test.php" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec)
[Fri Aug 17 12:40:12 2012] [error] [client X] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from    server "/home/testwh2/public_html/test.php"
```

thanks

EDIT: fixed using this http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/04/apache2-fastcgi/ , just need to suexec the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed FastCgiServer directive and now it is working perfectly , will post config soon for reference

/etc/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/mod_fastcgi.so

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        FastCgiWrapper /opt/csw/apache2/sbin/suexec
        FastCgiconfig -maxClassProcesses 1 -singleThreshold 1 -autoUpdate -idle-timeout 240 -pass-header HTTP_AUTHORIZ
ATION
        AddHandler  fastcgi-script              .fcgi .fcg .fpl
</IfModule>
```

vhost config
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/testwh2/cgi-bin/

```
<Directory "/cgi-bin/">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -Includes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

/home/testwh2/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi

```
#!/bin/bash
export PHPRC="path/to/php.ini"
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=20
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
exec /usr/local/fc_wrap/php5 "$@"
```