# mod_fcgid not using multiple php interpreters for concurrent requests

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid

I have the following problem with `mod_fcgid` on apache with php.

Everything runs without any errors but all my requests are processed by one php interpreter, even when I set `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN>1` and there are multiple php interpreters.  `FcgidMinProccessPerClass` also does nothing.

I discovered this using a sleep call into a test script.

Here is my config:

/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5

```
exec /usr/bin/php
```

/home/usercp/public_html/cgi-bin/php.fcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC="/home/usercp/public_html/php.ini"
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=10
exec /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
```

/etc/httpd/conf/php.conf

```
# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 1
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10

FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml
```

/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/usercp/vhost/fcgi.conf

```
<Location />
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
Options +ExecCGI
FcgidWrapper /home/usercp/public_html/cgi-bin/php.fcgi .php

# Customize the next two directives for your requirements.
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: How do you know all the requests are processed by one PHP interpreter?

Comment: i request a test.php with a sleep(10) two times and then a phpinfo page , the first last 10 sec , the second 20 and the third 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , config was OK , it was just firefox that queued the requests :D
no problem using wget and safari

switched to mod_fastcgi [Apache mod_fastcgi](https://serverfault.com/questions/418547/apache-mod-fastcgi)